# xamarin picker not binding

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, picker

I have multiple pickers in my project and for some reason just one of the pickers are not binding.  I've been messing with this for two days now and no matter if I change to observable collections or lists of strings its still not working.

here is the xaml

```
                <Picker x:Name="PickerMarket" Title="Market" ClassId="PickerMarket"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ShortDesc}"  
                    SelectedItem="{Binding ShortDesc}"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
            </Picker>
```

here is the viewModel

```
class VamiMarketViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Performance> _testList;
    public List<Performance> TestList
    {
        get { return _testList; }
        set
        {
            {
                _testList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _shortDesc;
    public string ShortDesc
    {
        get { return _shortDesc; }
        set
        {
            {
                _shortDesc = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Performance
{
    public int PerformanceDailyTableId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Filedate { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }

    public decimal TradeLevel { get; set; }
    public decimal BeginningEquity { get; set; }
    public decimal fxPL { get; set; }
    public decimal CashActivity { get; set; }
    public decimal CashActivityNonPl { get; set; }
    public decimal TBills { get; set; }
    public decimal OTEChange { get; set; }
    public decimal Realized { get; set; }
    public decimal Commission { get; set; }
    public decimal ClearingFees { get; set; }
    public decimal ExchangeFees { get; set; }
    public decimal NFAFees { get; set; }
    public decimal BrokerageFees { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionFees { get; set; }
    public decimal NetPerformance { get; set; }
    public decimal EndingEquity { get; set; }
    public decimal DailyROR { get; set; }
    public decimal Vami { get; set; }
    public decimal ADMstmtNLVchange { get; set; }
    public decimal ManualAdjustment { get; set; }
    public decimal DoubleCheck { get; set; }

    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Sector { get; set; }
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
}
```

in the creation of the view model just for testing purposes I am trying to populate the list like so

```
            Performance p1 = new Performance();
        p1.ShortDesc = "user";
        TestList.Add(p1);

        Performance p2 = new Performance();
        p2.ShortDesc = "stephen";
        TestList.Add(p2);
```

Comment: try `ItemDisplayBinding="ShortDesc"` - `ItemDisplayBinding` is the name of the property to use for display, not an actual binding expression

Comment: it won't let me do that... bad syntax in xaml?

Comment: I just double-checked the docs and apparently my memory is faulty - that property DOES expect a binding expression

Comment: thanks for checking... any other ideas why it is not working?

Comment: just confirmed it has something to do with my downloading data async... then whatever is done on that method does not get reflected in the UI.  is that normal?

Comment: without seeing the relevant code I can't say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To what I see from your code, the `SelectedItem` seems to be the problem. 
Since your `Picker`'s `ItemsSource`(TestList property) is of type `List<Performance>`, the `SelectedItem` property bound to the `Picker` must be of type `Performance`. But, in your case, you have kept it as `string` instead of `Performance`.

The `ItemDisplayBinding` must be the name of any property inside your `Performance` object which in your case is fine since you have a string property called `ShortDesc` inside your `Performance` class.

That's the problem I see in your code. Change the type of the property `ShortDesc` like below and assign any one of the items in your collection `TestList` to it. Your code will start working fine.

```
private Performance _shortDesc;
public Performance ShortDesc
{
   get { return _shortDesc; } 
   set
   {
       {
            _shortDesc = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
}
```

> Refer to the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding) which explains a clear example for Binding objects to Picker.

I hope that helps.

Comment: that was the issue thank you.  I changed to an observablecollection<performance>, then changed shortdes to Performance as well and it works